# Can't understand the use of the axis?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
# 'x' is [1, 4]
# 'y' is [2, 5]
# 'z' is [3, 6]
stack([x, y, z])  # => [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]] (Pack along first dim.)
stack([x, y, z], axis=1)  # => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

What does the 'axis' do here in this code ?

Comment: Assuming this is the [numpy stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) function, it is "The axis in the result array along which the input arrays are stacked." (You should add the numpy tag to the question.)

Comment: Actually this is a tensorflow stack function . And I don't get what axis 1 is .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TensorFlow's stack function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack). Axis tells you **the dimension along which** to stack your vectors.

It might be easier to think about if you change x, y, and z to a, b, and c. axis=0 means use the first element of a, b, and c to create the *elements of the first dimension of the result*. axis=1 means use the first element of a, b, and c to create the elements of the *second dimension of the result*.